# cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’

Tags: nvidia, jetson-xavier

In Nvidia jetson Xavier, when cmake CudaSift

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/local/CudaSift-Maxwell/build$ make
[ 14%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/cudasift.dir/cudasift_generated_matching.cu.o
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
CMake Error at cudasift_generated_matching.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
Error generating
/usr/local/CudaSift-Maxwell/build/CMakeFiles/cudasift.dir//./cudasift_generated_matching.cu.o
```

Comment: Seems there is wrong instruction set SSE2 for aarch64 architecture... Probably you've used a wrong package or config here.